# Performance of In-place permutation with std::move

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote an in-place permutation algorithm [an exercise in TAOCP3], where the inner loop is

```
template<typename T>
void inplace_permute(T *pT, int *P, const int n)
{
  // part of the inner loop
  pT[j] = std::move(pT[k]);
  P[j] = j;

  // more logic to update j, k, etc.
}
```

Here, `pT` is the array of elements to be sorted, `P` is the permutation table and `n` is the number of elements.

Will `std::move` increase performance if T is a complex type, e.g., a string? Also important, can it be optimized out if T is a primitive type (e.g., an int?)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does `TAOCP3` stand for ?

Comment: @SayemAhmed The Art of Computer Programming, volume 3 (Sorting and searching) by Donald Knuth.

Comment: Wouldn't `swap` be better? After all you need all the values anyway...

Comment: @AdamBadura swap would use ~3n assignments, whereas this uses ~n.

Comment: @zvrba Not necessarily... Complex object is swapped by swapping its members. That is nearly sure IMHO. Simple objects could be swapped with dedicated processor instructions (providing compiler does it - yet this I find doubtful). And with moving you have to do some special moves anyway to prevent overwriting of elements...

Comment: @AdamBadura Consider somewhat simpler task: `tmp=std::move(A[0])`, `A[0]=std::move(A[1])`, ..., `A[n-1]=std::move(tmp)`. `swap` would use 3 assignments in each step instead of one. It's simpler even for complex types (e.g., string) since the move target is always empty.

Comment: @zvrba I see this as `swap(A[0],A[1])`, `swap(A[1],A[2])`, ..., `swap(A[n-2],A[n-1])`, which involves n-1 exchanges of values. While exchange could be done (yet this depends on compiler and target machine) as a single instruction (for example `XCHG`).

Comment: @zvrba Anyway that was just a thought. I do not claim it is better that way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll sum up your question as:

> What does `std::move` do ?

Basically, `std::move` makes the use of Move Constructor and Move Assignment Operator available.

Typically, those are close to a bitwise copy (they are *not* exactly one), and so the performance is usually related to the `sizeof` the class.

Therefore, `std::move(someint)` and `std::move(somestring)` would have similar performance if they had a similar size, even though one is a built-in and the other a user class.

There are some differences though.

- on a built-in, a move is just a bitwise copy. Because the moved-from value is unspecified, no zeroing is required. You may want, after moving, to assign it a known value (0 or whatever)
- on a user class, which typically has *resources* (such a dynamically allocated buffer), moving implies: cleaning the moved-to instance (for assignment), making a somewhat bitwise copy, resetting the moved-from instance. So there is a bit more work.

To understand, we can illustrate this with an example string implementation:

```
class String {
public:
  // Many things
  String(String&& right);
  String& operator=(String right);

  friend void swap(String& left, String& right);

private:
  // On 64 bits platform, 4x as big as an `int`
  size_t capacity;
  size_t size;
  char* buffer;
};

// Move Constructor
String::String(String&& right):
   capacity(right.capacity), size(right.size), buffer(right.buffer)
{
  right = String(); // reset right
}


// Assignment Operator
String& String::operator=(String right) {
  swap(*this, right);
  return *this;
}

// Swap
void swap(String& left, String& right) {
  using std::swap;
  swap(left.capacity, right.capacity);
  swap(left.size    , right.size);
  swap(left.buffer  , right.buffer);
}
```

As you can see, the assignment `pT[j] = std::move(pT[k]);` means (semantically):

- creating a temporary (make a bitwise copy of `pT[k]`)
- reset `pT[k]`
- exchange the state between the temporary and `pT[j]`
- destroy the temporary (which typically release the storage inherited from `pT[j]`)

The compiler should, more or less, be able to optimize it into:

- exchange the state between `pT[j]` and `pT[k]`
- destroy `pT[k]` (just release the storage)
- rebuild a new instance in `pT[k]`

Or, crudely:

```
swap(ptj, ptk);    // swap 3 fields
delete ptk.buffer; // might be a no-op
ptk = String();    // 0-out 3 fields
```

Note: this is a toy implementation, it would be a bit more simple on gcc and much more complex on VC++ as they use different representations of the data.

Comment: Had you implemented move-assignment `String& operator=(String&& rhs)`, would its implementation be the same (except the reset-part) as for move-constructor?

Comment: @zvrba: it depends on the guarantees you want to establish. Here I chose the Strong Exception Guarantee typical implementation known as Copy and Swap, and hope that the compiler will optimize if the swaps are trivial (ie, built-in types). You can also implement it directly, however I consider it a loss of time usually, duplicates many code (copy and move constructor + swap already list all arguments, and thus increase the chance to miss an update when changing the class).

Answer (score 1):

If `T` has a move assignment operator, that will be used for rvalues and possibly improve performance.

If the type doesn't have move assignment, but does have copy assignment (like `int`), the value will be copied instead.